# How to delete the black background of this image and crop out the target part from it?

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, edge-detection

[image]

How can I remove the black background from this image and crop the label out?

[image]

I tried edge detection, but I found that due to the target being only on the right side of the image, the boundary cannot be detected on the right side, resulting in the inability to proceed. I spliced another black image on the right side, as shown in the second image. However, due to the fact that the blue area above turned black after binarization during the experiment, the complete outermost boundary could not be detected, and it was ultimately unsuccessful.

Comment: Convert the input image to `HSV`, split the `V` channel, threshold, some morphology may be needed to clean up the result, look for external contours and filter by aspect ratio/area, poly-approximate the filtered contour to a quadrilateral, get the four corner points, numpy-slice the original image based on that information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).